# C# WinForms custom control default properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, controls

How to you set the default properties for custom controls, i.e. when they are first dragged onto the form in the Designer?

Can't find an answer here or via Google; all I get is how to constrain the values.

Using Width & Height as examples, if I set them in the constructor they get applied to the control everytime the Designer is opened. How do I set them to a default which is never applied again after the user changes the properties?

Comment: Could you give an example of how to apply that to base class properties?

Comment: Apologies - it's `[DefaultValue(someValue)]`. Here's a link to the MSDN on it with example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I think DefaultValue attribute is what you need. The Visual Studio IDE will put the default value specified in the attribute in the Designer file. If user will change the default value to some other value, Visual Studio IDE will update the Designer file with new value. This will prevent reloading previous value when control will be reopened as the default value has already been overwritten.

Comment: I can't find a way to apply this to the base class properties (Width & Height).

Comment: @TobyWilson Did you ever figure out a way to accomplish this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @tmwoods I'm afraid I don't remember, it's a long time since I did any winforms now.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) attribute.

```
private int height;

[DefaultValue(50)]
public int Height
{
    get 
    {
       return height;
    }
    set 
    {
       height=value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the base class property for Height isn't overridden by it.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me for properties that I can't override is using the `new` operator. For example, the `MultiSelect` property on a `ListView` control. I want `MultiSelect` to default to `false`, but I still want to be able to change it.

If I just set it to `false` in the constructor, or in `InitializeComponent`, the problem (I think) is that the default value is still `true`, so if I set the value to `true` in the designer, the designer notices that `true` is the default, and so just doesn't set the property at all rather than explicitly setting it to what it thinks is already the default. But then the value ends up being `false` instead, because that is what is set in the constructor.

To get around this issue I used the following code:

```
/// <summary>Custom ListView.</summary>
public sealed partial class DetailsListView : ListView
{
   ...

   [DefaultValue(false)]
   public new bool MultiSelect {
      get { return base.MultiSelect; }
      set { base.MultiSelect = value; }
   }
```

This allows the control to still have a functioning `MultiSelect` property that defaults to `false` rather than `true`, and the property can still be toggled on the new control.

EDIT: I encountered an issue having to do with using abstract forms. I've been using abstract form classes, with a concrete implementation that I switch to when I need to use the designer. I found that when I switched the class that I was inheriting from that the properties on my custom control would reset to the old defaults. I seem to have corrected this behaviour by setting properties to their defaults in the constructor of the custom control.

Answer (score -1):

In the constructor, set the values of your properties you want to appear when you drag it onto the canvas.
Or if they are the built in properties of the base control then set them in the designer code class.

Comment: Setting the properties in the constructor causes them to be applied every time the designer is opened, effectively meaning they can't be set.

Answer (score -1):

The below will allow you to add the value when you display the form, after that you can set it as you want.

```
private int widthLength = 5;  

public int Width {      

     get { return widthLength ; } 
     set { widthLength = value;   
}
```

Comment: Using this, the default properties don't get applied when the control is dragged onto the form in the Designer. I also get a compiler warning that it hides the inherited member; adding 'new' as instructed by the warning doesn't change the behaviour.